# Would making a satirical version of someone else's character get me sued?

Tags: legal, copyright, character-development

Licensing the rights to a popular character is definitely a hard process. Rather than licensing the rights to (insert hero here), what if I were to make a satirical version of the IP owner's character(s) like *Spaceballs* did? What sort of legal trouble could I face for making a satirical rip-off of a character?

Comment: This question does not appear to be specific to game development, since as you point out, parody happens routinely in other media like film. Why not ask on a law site instead if it's not game development expertise that you need?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to game development.

Comment: Actually, this falls under Parody, which is completely legal.  As long as you make it clear that this is not the original character(so you dont breach trademark) but use a different name you should be fine.  Interestingly enough, I believe one of the things the courts look at for parodies is whether or not they are satirical.

Comment: It is still possible to get sued though, because large companies have a ton of money to throw at lawsuits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone can sue you for anything. The question is not just if you would have the legal standing to win, but also if you could afford to fight a lawsuit. Because defending against a copyright or trademark lawsuit is expensive, and you need to pay your lawyers up-front.

In some (not all) jurisdictions, "satire" is a possible fair-use exception from copyright. But that does not mean that every court will see your satire as satire, and not possibly as infringement at best or defamation at worst. So when you can not afford a good lawyer, then you should be very careful about using other people's IP in the hope that saying it's a satire will protect you.

By the way, when Mel Brooks made Spaceballs, [he actually did negotiate with Lucas Film about how far he could go without them sending their lawyers after him](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/241705/16995). Part of that agreement was that there would be no merchandise for Spaceballs and that he would hire their subsidiary *Industrial Light & Magic* for the special effects.